# Dynamic clock: image change by computer's clock

Tags: javascript, image, time, rotation, clock

I want an image to change every minute according to a user's clock. Moreover, I would like the image to be tied to a specific HH:MM. So when the computer moves from 3:00pm to 3:01pm ...back to 2:59pm, I would like the image to move from 0001.jpg to 0002.jpg....to 1440.jpg. Then have the process repeat with 3:00pm and 0001.jpg. The idea is that the sequence does not start over at 0001.jpg each time the user browses to the site.

I would like to know if:

1. javascript or php is better
2. I should put all 1440 jpg images in an array or a data base

Thank you,

tora

Comment: How about:  3.  Rethink your design...1440 images...seriously?

Comment: If you're saying that the images correspond to the user's system time, then you have to use javascript. If you're dealing with 1440 images (?!), you should probably handle 'em with a database.

Comment: @bpaulon: They are around 500kb

Comment: @Gerrat: Nope, there are 1440 minutes in a day, so need that many pictures to have a unique photo for each minute.

Comment: @squibe: Thought so with the javascript, and I will start with a database (mysql perhaps?)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd approach it, in a nutshell:

1. Make sure your webserver is configured to send caching information so the browser doesn't have to load any image more than once for at least several days.  500k * 1440 = a lot of bandwidth.
2. Use javascript; every *t* minutes start a batch download and get the images you need for the next *t* minutes, storing them in an array.
3. Every 60 seconds, pop an image off your stack and into your UI.

Comment: I would do the same. Look that the question about whether php or javascript shows some lack of study on this languages (or detailement of your question). You can host all server side on php (or rails, whatever) and then keep calling asynchronously for the new images by javascript. You may have some problem with caching if you are intending to keep the users for a long time. Good idea for a site though

Answer (score 0):

1440 images is definitely not the way to approach this.
If you are into HTML5, http://ineedmoretime.org/ has a cool implementation.

It can be easily reproduced.  ( Watch link at Chrome / Safari / Firefox as it needs SVG)
Created a fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/kx5cT/

P.S: I am hot linking http://ineedmoretime.org/images/clock-background.png as of now in the javascript. Please place it in your on folder.

Comment: yeah, but I am not making a regular clock. The pictures are of my wife and I, though she would enjoy this (and I have way too much time on my hands....oh boy)